# How to proof that if a sequence is Cauchy, the sequence of its norms converges?

Tags: uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

I was asked to proof that if the sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence in a normed space, then the sequence of norms $\{\Vert x \Vert\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges.

I started by using the subtraction version of the triangle inequality and assuming $\Vert . \Vert_{1}$ as the corresponding norm.

$$\vert \Vert x_{n} \Vert - \Vert x_{m} \Vert \vert \leq \Vert x_{n} - x_{m} \Vert$$

But I only concluded with the sequence of norms being Cauchy, which doesn't necessarily implies it converges.

$$\Vert x_{n} - x_{m} \Vert < \epsilon$$

$$\vert \Vert x_{n} \Vert - \Vert x_{m} \Vert \vert \leq \Vert x_{n} - x_{m} \Vert < \epsilon$$

$$\vert \Vert x_{n} \Vert - \Vert x_{m} \vert \vert  < \epsilon$$

From here I just got stuck, and don't know how to proceed. I was also thinking of assuming that, since the norm is in either $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$  (both complete spaces), then the sequence should converge.

Thanks...

Comment: Normed vector spaces exist for all sorts of fields, not only $\mathbf  R$ or $\mathbf  C$.

Comment: Your last idea is the good one: you are let with a sequence $(||x_n||)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of elements of the complete space $\mathbb{R}$, this sequence is Cauchy, thus it converges.

Comment: The values of a norm lie in $\mathbb{R}$. So your argument is correct.

Comment: From Cauchy you obtain boundedness. From boundedness exist converged subsequence i.e. limit point. Then all sequence converged to that point.